# Private метод не срабатывает

Tags: php

Задача такова: Дополните класс Worker private методом checkAge, который будет проверять возраст на корректность (от 1 до 100 лет). Этот метод должен использовать метод setAge перед установкой нового возраста (если возраст не корректный - он не должен меняться).

С public методом checkAge все работает корректно, а вот с private так и не получилось.

```
class Worker{

    private $name;
    private $age;
    private $salary;

    public function setAge($age){
        if (is_numeric($age)){
            $this->age = $age;
        } else{
            die("could not set age");
        }
    }

    public function getAge(){
        return $this->age;
    }

    private function checkAge(){
        $min = 1;
        $max = 100;
        if ($this->age >= $min && $this->age <= $max){
            return $this->age;
        } else{
            die("different age");
        }
    }
}

$workerOne = new Worker;

$workerTwo = new Worker;

$workerOne->setAge(25);

echo $workerOne->checkAge();
```

Comment: внутри `setAge` перед тем как присвоить `$this->age` сделайте проверку через `$this->checkAge()` - в условиях задачи же все ясно сказано. Только сделайте чтобы `checkAge()` возвращал `boolean` и при вызове внутри `setAge()` проверяйте если `checkAge()` вернет `true` то делайте `$this->age=$age` иначе нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Worker{

    private $name;
    private $salary;
    private $age;

    public function getAge() 
    {
        return $this->age;
    }

    public function setAge($age): void 
    {
        if (!is_numeric($age)) {
            die("Age is not numberic value.");
        }

        if ($this->checkAge($age)) {
            $this->age = $age;
        }

        echo 'Age has been successfully set.';
    }

    private function checkAge($age): bool 
    {
        $min = 1;
        $max = 100;

        if ($age >= $min && $age <= $max){
            return true;
        }

        die("Age value is out of range.");
    }
}

----- Клиентский код -----
(new Worker)->setAge(25); // выведет `Age has been successfully set.`
```

---

1. Советую прочитать про модификаторы доступа в PHP, довольно простая тема, довольно неплохо раскрыта [тут](https://metanit.com/php/tutorial/6.3.php). Вкратце, то private модификатор доступа ограничивает вас областью видимости текущего класса, т.е. вы можете использовать его только внутри методов класса, в котором он описан (имеются исключительные ситуации, где это можно обойти, но это не ваш случай).
2. Метод проверки возраста должен быть вызван перед его установкой, т.к. если он не входит в диапазон, то дальнейшее выполнение программы - бессмысленно. В данном случае, тема будет уже сложней, но не менее полезная. Про программирование по контракту можно почитать [тут](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83), хоть код и на Java, но примеры очень показательны и понятны.